# Displaying image from database in listview

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

So I have a table named apps with 4 columns and a column named App_icon in which I convert the drawable to byte[] and store it in the colum "App_icon" as blob. I have a listview where it picks up the fields from the table as shows it. I need to also show the image at the left corner by converting back the blob to image.The code I use to retrieve the text data from the db and to display is:

```
mySQLiteAdapter.open();

    String[] arrayColumns = new String[] { Dbhelper.KEY_PKG,
            Dbhelper.KEY_APP, };
    int[] arrayViewIDs = new int[] { R.id.appname, R.id.pkgname };

    cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllFolders();

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_items,
            cursor, arrayColumns, arrayViewIDs);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

Where KEY_PKG and KEY_APP are the other table names which is displayed in textview (appname and pkgname). Could someone provide a sample code on how to bind the image to the respective fields?
Regards,
Vijai

Edit: If anyone can post how to get only the values of "App_icon" column from all the rows and store it in an array? That would be helppful

Edit 2: Below is the method used to get the image

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue (View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
            if (view.getId() == R.id.app_icon) {
                ImageView IV=(ImageView) view;
                Bitmap icon;
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                byte[] image = null;
                Cursor images = mySQLiteAdapter.geticon();
                int rows = images.getCount();


                for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++){
                    image = mySQLiteAdapter.getIcon(i);            
                    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image , 0, image .length, options);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "executes"+rows, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    IV.setImageBitmap(icon);
                }

                //IV.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                return true;
           }
            return false;
}

});
```

Comment: so you want to convert byte[] to bitmap ?

Comment: @Moh.Sukhni Yeah...have to convert it to bitmap and then add it to the listview.

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid as far as I read, It doesnt even talk about images.

Comment: yes if i talk about customization that it means it may have any thing even list view in list view you can get your image view change your blob to bitmap and set it to imageview as simple as it could be

Comment: Ok...Can any one of you say how do I get only the values of "App_icon" column from all the rows and store it in an array? Because I dono sqlite, I'm confused.

Comment: @user2515577 : ask a separate question for it stating the issues it any easy job search for sqlite tut without sqlite operation how you are thingking to access database

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid Ok...done my research, reading etc..and came up with the method added the question to get the byte array from the DB, convert it into image back and then add it to image view. And it works. But currently, the problem is, the imageview is set with the image which is in the last row of DB. which I understood is because the imageview doesnt change with position of the adapter. So How do I set the correct image to the correct position? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple function that convert byte[]  to bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! I will use this instead of what I have now as this looks more powerful than my previous one!

Answer (score 0):

First convert the byte array to bitmap, and then bind to the view. so custom a adapter may solve it.